# Forwarding stdin to a subprocess in Ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, io, stdin

I am developing a wrapper for [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io), which at some point during its execution, it may request user input. So, my application must forward everything typed on its stdin to the subprocess' stdin. The following solution works on Linux, but in Windows the subprocess (Terraform) seems to never receive the input:

```
require 'open3'

def exec(cmd)
  Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
    stdout_thread = Thread.new do
      IO.copy_stream(stdout, STDOUT)
    end

    stderr_thread = Thread.new do
      IO.copy_stream(stderr, STDERR)
    end

    stdin_thread = Thread.new do
      IO.copy_stream(STDIN, stdin)
    end

    puts "Return code: #{thread.value}"

    stdin_thread.join
    stdout_thread.join
    stderr_thread.join
  end
end

exec('terraform destroy')
```

This solution actually works on Windows when executing some applications that require user input different than Terraform. But, the following two implementations (in Go and Python) are capable of forwarding their stdin to Terraform on Windows. So, it might be the case that my Ruby code has some issue, or perhaps Ruby's implementation for Windows has some limitation when dealing with process execution and input forwarding.

Is anyone aware of such a limitation?

Python example:

```
import subprocess
import sys

with subprocess.Popen(['terraform', 'destroy'],
                      stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=sys.stdout) as proc:
    proc.wait()
```

Go example:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("terraform", "destroy")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    go func() {
        defer stdout.Close()
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer stderr.Close()
        io.Copy(os.Stderr, stderr)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer stdin.Close()
        io.Copy(stdin, os.Stdin)
    }()

    err = cmd.Run()
    log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
}
```

Comment: [Disclaimer: I didn't even look at your code.] You might want to try JRuby. Ironically, it is more compatible with Ruby than YARV (aka "Ruby") itself on Windows, and more "native". The reason is that YARV's implementation of I/O and process management is just a thin wrapper around POSIX, and things working different (or not at all) is actually expected and not considered a bug. JRuby OTOH *must* emulate everything anyway, by virtue of being hosted on the Java platform, and thus works consistently on *all* platforms, and tries to closely match the behavior of YARV on Linux.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It indeed works with JRuby... So, your guess is that there would not be even an attempt to address this in YARV if reported, right?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to try, does it? You just need to be prepared to get "`open3` depends on POSIX `open` and Windows is not POSIX, use a POSIX environment such as cygwin or Bash for Windows instead" as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet based on `IO.popen` seems to work. It executes a command, and it returns the command output as an array containing the output lines. Optionally, the output is written to stdout too.

```
def run(cmd, directory: Dir.pwd, print_output: true)
  out = IO.popen(cmd, err: %i[child out], chdir: directory) do |io|
    begin
      out = ''
      loop do
        chunk = io.readpartial(4096)
        print chunk if print_output
        out += chunk
      end
    rescue EOFError; end
    out
  end

  $?.exitstatus.zero? || (raise "Error running command #{cmd}")

  out.split("\n")
     .map { |line| line.tr("\r\n", '') }
end
```

Comment: This works nicely. Have used it with Vagrant to adapt bridged network to the existing environment as I move my laptop from one work setting to another. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dpneumo/04dff92ad038c79b8b70f0fbb35f1beb)

Answer (score 0):

@betabandido
This works as well.

```
def run(cmd, directory: Dir.pwd, print_output: true)
  out = IO.popen(cmd, err: %i[child out], chdir: directory) do |io|
    io.readlines
  end
  raise "Error running command #{cmd}" unless $?.exitstatus.zero?
  print out if print_output
  out
end
```